# Characters with ASCII > 128 are not correctly read in Javascript

Tags: javascript, utf-8, character-encoding, non-ascii-characters, windows-1252

I have a HTML that includes a Javascript file. This script contains a special character, ASCII 152. When I try to display the charCodeAt, I get different results, but never the right one. Could you please advice? Thanks

**TEST.HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset=SEE BELOW src="test.js">
</script>
```

**TEST.JS file with ANSI encoding**

```
function d(a)
{
a=(a+"").split("");
alert(a[1].charCodeAt(0));
};
d("i˜g"); // Note that ˜ is 152 in ASCII
```

- TEST.HTML with x-user-defined charset: alert shows 63384. With %63232 works, as every char >128 is displayed as 63232+char.
- TEST.HTML with utf-8 charset: alert shows 65533. All chars > 128 are displayed as 65533.
- TEST.HTML with Windows-1252 charset: alert shows 752. I cannot find a relation between ASCII and what is displayed.

**TEST.JS file with UTF-8 encoding**

```
function d(a)
{
a=(a+"").split("");
alert(a[1].charCodeAt(0));
};
d("i[x98]g"); // Note that x98 is 152
```

- TEST.HTML with x-user-defined charset: alert shows 65533. All chars > 128 are displayed as 65533.
- TEST.HTML with utf-8 charset: alert shows 65533. All chars > 128 are displayed as 65533.
- TEST.HTML with Windows-1252 charset: alert shows 65533. All chars > 128 are displayed as 65533.

Comment: There is no characters in range 127-255 for utf8, and ASCII ends at 127... Also the character at position `1` in `"i[x98]g"` is a `"["`

Comment: "˜" is not at position 152 in any encoding I'm aware of.

Comment: Please see www.ascii-code.com (ASCII extended)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no characters in range 128-255 for utf8, and ASCII ends completely at 127... Also the character at position `1` in `"i[x98]g"` is a `"["`, the `"[x98]"` is meaningless.

Your function can be replaced with `str.charCodeAt(1)`.

The character `˜` is 
[Unicode Character 'SMALL TILDE' (U+02DC](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2dc/index.htm) and can be written as `"\u02DC"`, or `String.fromCharCode(732)`

Comment: Additional info: [charCodeAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) works with Unicode and does not really care about ASCII.

Comment: Sorry, I meant ASCII EXTENDED. As per below, 152 is '˜'
http://www.ascii-code.com/

[x98] is one character. It is the way Notepad++ represents that 152 char in UTF-8. 98 in hexadecimal is 152.

Comment: Thank you all. Then I rephrase my question. I want to write a character representing integer 152 in TEST.JS as parameter of d(), so that when I run this function alert displays 152. I am open to use any encoding.

Comment: @Arturo in that case you can to write `"\u0098"`, or this invisible character: `""`, or `String.fromCharCode(152)`

Comment: @Arturo, that’s a completely new question and should be asked separately. I cannot make sense of that question either, as there is no character representing integer 152. If you wish to map characters to integers according to a scheme of your own, or applying someone else’s mapping, use table for that. But it is difficult to guess what might be the real question here.

Comment: I believe there is some kind of problem between chars 152 (\u0098) and 732 (\u02dc), as both are displayed with the same symbol. How can I force charCodeAt() to use the correct one (152)?
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2dc/index.htm
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/098/index.htm

Comment: Thank you all. As suggested, I have opened a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080605/special-character-u0098-read-as-u02dc-using-charcodeat

Answer (score 0):

ASCII only has 127 characters. char 152 is non-existant

Comment: Sorry, I meant ASCII EXTENDED. As per below, 152 is '˜'
http://www.ascii-code.com/